# Find the limit. (If an answer does not exist, enter DNE.) $lim_{x \to \infty} {\sqrt{9x^2 + x}− 3x}$

Tags: calculus

Is my process is correct?

Also, why is one to allowed to divide the variable in the radical by its highest power?

$$ \lim_ {x-> \infty} \sqrt { 9 x^2 +x} - 3 x $$

Comment: Because $\frac{1}{x}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}}$

Comment: Also note that where you have $\frac{x}{\frac{1}{x}}$, it should simply say $\frac{x}{x}$, in case that is causing you any additional confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{9x^2+x}+3x}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{9x^2+x}+3x}\times\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{x}}$$
$$=\frac{\frac{x}{x}}{\frac{\sqrt{9x^2+x}+3x}{x}}=\frac{\frac{x}{x}}{\frac{\sqrt{9x^2+x}}{x}+\frac{3x}{x}}$$$$=\frac{\frac{x}{x}}{\frac{\sqrt{9x^2+x}}{\sqrt{x^2}}+\frac{3x}{x}}=\frac{\frac{x}{x}}{\sqrt{\frac{9x^2+x}{x^2}}+\frac{3x}{x}}$$

Comment: Why am I allowed to divide the power under the radical to be x^2?

Comment: Because dividing by $x$ is the same as dividing by $\sqrt{x^2}$. And, $\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}=\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}$

Comment: shouldn't you be using the limit laws?

Comment: The algebraic manipulations shown above apply everywhere - nothing here is specific to limits